# using git-bash on windows

Tags: git, git-bash

I was trying to clone a local Git repository from the Apache repository. This is what I did

```
git clone git://git.apache.org/hadoop-common.git
```

I used "git-bash" on the windows.

[image]

How to do it correctly?

Comment: what is Git's version?

Comment: are you behind firewall or proxy?

Comment: The Git' version is Git-1.8.4-preview20130916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is usually the firewall problem. Please see the below discussion of this issue on msysgit:
https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=375